# add series (row?) number to end of existing column data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a large table with a column that contains the same string data "Dummy".
I need to add a sequential count to the end of that string to make it unique.  IE:

```
Dummy1
Dummy2
Dummy3
```

For the life of me I cannot get this right.  I do not want a new column, and I do not want a new table.

Comment: For what version of SQL Server?  2005+ supports [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 select columnname + ' ' +  rank() OVER (ORDER BY columnname) as data
   from tablename
```

Comment: Actually came up with this and it worked:

Update your_table
Set col_name = rtrim(col_name) + '-' + row_no
From 
(
select col_name, row_no = Cast (ROW_NUMBER () Over (order by col_name) AS varchar) FROM your_table
)your_table